# Castle Windsor: How to programatically pass a list parameter to the container?

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Is it possible to pass a list constructor parameter when resolving a type? I want to use a programmatic configuration if possible. I've been playing around with the Parameters method as shown below, but I've not yet stumbled upon the answer.

```
container.Register(
    Component
    .For<IDoSomething>()
    .ImplementedBy<DoSomething>()
    .Parameters(...)
);
```

The DoSomething class would look something like this

```
public class DoSomething : IDoSomething
{
    public DoSomething(List<string> listOfStrings) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aha!

```
container.Register(
    Component
    .For<IDoSomething>()
    .ImplementedBy<DoSomething>()
    .Parameters(new { listOfStrings = someList })
);
```