# Data Driven IoC

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am writing a program that uses IoC(Windsor v3.0) at startup to load all assemblies in a directory, if implementing an interface/service, into a repository for the core of the application. I am, however, a newcomer to Windsor. My app polls a DB table and when it finds a row that needs to be processed, it checks the name of the service to process the record and requests it from the repository. I can load all the modules into the dictionary and then into the repository via configuration as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890287/windsor-castle-inject-dictionary-of-interfaces-via-configuration). Good and well, but I **need** it to be more dynamic.

How I envision it (pseudo-code):

```
List<string> enabledServices = GetServicesFromDb();
IDictionary<string, IModule> dict = new IDictionary<string, IModule>();

//Load the assemblies (This works currently!)
_container.Register(AllTypes
                   .FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("Modules"))
                   .BasedOn<IModule>());

// Build dictionary
foreach(string service in enabledServices)
{
     foreach(?? asmble in _container.assemblies)
     {
         if(asmble.Id == service)
             dict.Add(service, asmble);
     }
}

// Register the repository from constructed dictionary
_container.Register(
    Component
    .For<IModuleRepository>()
    .ImplementedBy<IntegrationRepository>()
    .Parameters(new { modules = dict})
);
```

The repository:

```
public class IntegrationRepository : IModuleRepository
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, IModule> _modules;

    public IntegrationRepository(IDictionary<string, IModule> modules)
    {
        _modules = modules;
    }

    public IModule GetModule(string moduleName)
    {
        return _modules.ContainsKey(moduleName) ? _modules[moduleName] : null;
    }
}
```

IModule looks like this:

```
public interface IModule : IDisposable
{
    string Id { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    bool Enabled { get; set; }
    bool Validate();
    string EmailSubject { get; }
}
```

All modules:

1. Implement "IModule" interface
2. Reside in the "Modules" subfolder
3. Share a common namespace

I don't have enough experience with Windsor to know how to iterate through the container or if its possible, and _container.ResolveAll(); doesn't seem to work... at least the way I have it in my mind.

My thoughts come from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368866/castle-windsor-how-to-programatically-pass-a-list-parameter-to-the-container) which alludes to passing the object in if the object is already created. [And this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165427/convert-castle-windsor-xml-config-to-c-sharp-code) which is similar. I also saw some interesting things on the [DictionaryAdapterFactory()](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/10/Castle-DictionaryAdapter.aspx) but not confident enough to know how to use it

Is something like this possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of all this you can just store your container globally and you can resolve by full name your modules everywhere

```
_container.Resolve<IModule>(serviceFullName)
```

Comment: why make things complicated? :)

Answer (score 0):

you can register all available services to your container and then create a provider that returns only the services that are enabled in the database. Your components then should of course only access these services through the provider.

Comment: That is the goal of having a repository. :) My question centers on how to fluently get the assemblies into the repository in the first place. It is looking as though I might have to wrap the container instead of a dictionary.